# Set list of property in jsp from java class

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I have a list of objects like

`ArrayList<FieldTo> fieldsList;`

and  `FieldTo` has

```
private long fieldId;

private String category;

private Organization organization; ... etc with getter and setter
```

How can i set this `fieldId` , `category`, etc as property in jsp.

Please mention in detail, you are explaining to a fresher in struts

**Note:** Iam using table in jsp to set these values

Comment: What do you mean by *How can i set this `fieldId`, `category`, etc as property in jsp*?

Comment: I can keep track changes in this value if i set that as property="category" in jsp. How to do that

Comment: And sorry to be harsh but the fact you're new to a certain technology doesn't mean we should go *easy* with our answers. You should prepare yourself to understand the background concepts the proposed answers may lie, this site is not to post a long blog entry for a single person.

Comment: yeah, i understand your view. you can sugguest me a way itself in brief

Comment: Will this values be for display purposes only?

Comment: "Iam using table in jsp to set these values", well can you show the relevant JSP code also. Because as of now, reading your post, reading your post it's hard to tell what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No i need to track change on submit, there are several rows . so tracking in UI will be difficult

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a form and you have this arraylist in your form

**You Action form:**

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm{
    public List<FieldTo> fieldsList;
    //getters setters

}
```

**You jsp page:**

```
<logic:iterate name="nameOfMyForm" property=""fieldsList" id="field" type="com.package.FieldTo">
    <td><bean:write name="field" property="fieldId"></td>
    <td><bean:write name="field" property="category"></td>
    <td><bean:write name="field" property="organization.name"></td>
</logic:iterate>
```

**Organization.java**

```
public Class Organization{
    private String name; 
    //getters and settersa
}
```